# (Comment out)/wrap multiple lines of CSS with inline and multi-line comments already present

Tags: css, comments

I am trying to identify the rogue CSS element/line in my CSS file, and I would like to comment out sections of code, that already have comments in them, both inline, and multiline.   I am under the assumtion that as soon as the end identifier `*/` is read, no matter how many layers/levels/nests in/down you are, the `*/` ends the multi line comment.

Here is example code:

```
code 1;
code 2; /* current inline comment*/
code 3;
/* current multi line comment
code 4;
code 5;
*/
code 6; /* current inline comment */
code 7;
code 8;
```

I would like to be able to select codes 3 through 7, and wrap it with `/*` and `*/` and it comment out all of it.   How would I approach this?

Comment: Why not use `//`?  OOPS! I MEANT: Why not just use the `<!--` ... `-->` comment markers?

Comment: @JesseChisholm CSS doesn't support that. The only comment in CSS is with `/* */`

Comment: Sorry for the edited comment.  Thought I got in there before you had a chance to read it.  According to [this link at CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/) the HTML comment markers should work there.

Comment: @JesseChisholm It doesn't actually say that. On the contrary, it says <!-- .. --> "do not delimit CSS comments".

Comment: @MrLister - I stand corrected. That's what I get for reading too fast - it recognizes `<!--` and `-->` but assumes `rules` are in between, and the SGML comment markers are for the outer parser, not the CSS parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the unwanted code in a media type that doesn't exist.

```
@media DISABLED {
    unwanted code here
}
```

Sort of unrelated:

In languages where `//` or `--` can do a single-line comment, and editors that support this, I love keyboard shortcuts that do comments for you. In Visual Studio, for example, I can hit `ctrl k, c` and it will comment the selected text with single line comments. `ctrl k, u` just removes the `//` from the beginning of each selected line!

Comment: @Pacerier I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Pacerier saying the exact same thing doesn't really help in me understanding it better. Can you elaborate? Example maybe?